# How to Creat Excel Custom Function by API Javascript using VSTO?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

In API-js i can `create some custom function` then assign to button to `ribbon or Task panel` and I have seen a few instructions for creating functions using `yeoman and vscode` (example: `contoso.add(first,second)` in excel function) .

but I have not seen any documentation to guide `how to create custom function with parameter by using vsto`.

Can you give me more information or documents about this issue?
Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio tools for office doesn’t support the office js api, but you can use Visual Studio 2019 to create a excel web add-in project containing custom functions.

There is one caveat however in that currently you won’t be able to debug the custom function from visual studio, for that you would need to use vs code, or side load in Excel for the web and use the browser’s F12 tools to debug.

Comment: Hi. That's what I'm interested in
I am trying by adding my custom function to the function.js file(using vsto2019) but it did not work. can you guide it a little more..It seems that I have been missing some steps because I just beginer.
Thanks you!

Comment: I also need this, VSTO cannot make UDF, so i need to add it somehow, and if making function in a .js file in visual studio and integrating that to my VSTO add-in is possible. that'd solve my problem.